# How can I apply timed back pressure in RxJS5?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, rxjs5, reactivex

Imagine I have the following code:

```
let a = Rx.Observable.of(1, 2, 3)
let b = Observable.zip(a, a, (a, b) => a + b)
b.forEach(t => console.log(t))
```

This immediately outputs the results. Now, how do I put a timed delay between each message as a **way of back-pressure** (note that I don't want a buffer; instead, I want `a` and `b` to become **Cold Observables**), like:

```
b.takeEvery(1000).forEach(t => console.log(t))
```

And have the exact same answer:

```
<wait 1s>
2
<wait 1s>
4
<wait 1s>
6
```

---

**Alternative:** If backpressure (ou pull mechanisms for some observables) is something not supported in RxJS, then how could one create an infinite generator without running out of resources?

**Alternative 2:** Other JS frameworks that support both pull and push mechanisms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of RxJS 5.x back pressure is not support, but there is for example [`pausable` operator](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/pausable.md) in 4.x version. It works only with hot observables. More info on back pressure in case of [4.x](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/backpressure.md) and [here](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/backpressure.html) (especially take a loot at the bottom and RxJS related description).

This Erik Meijer's tweet may be bit controversial but relevant: https://twitter.com/headinthebox/status/774635475071934464

For your own implementation of back pressure mechanism you need to have 2-way communication channel, which can be fairly easily created with 2 subjects - one for each end. Basically use `next` for sending messages and `.subscribe` for listing to the other end.

Creating a generator is doable as well - again using a subject to bridge between push- and pull-based worlds. Below an exemplary implementation for generating Fibonacci numbers.

```js
const fib = () => {
  const n = new Rx.Subject()
  const f = n
    .scan(c => ({ a: c.b, b: c.b + c.a }), { a: 0, b: 1 })
    .map(c => c.a)
    
  return {
    $: f,
    next: () => n.next()
  }
}

const f = fib()

f.$.subscribe(n => document.querySelector('#r').innerHTML = n)
Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.querySelector('#f'), 'click')
  .do(f.next)
  .subscribe()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.js"></script>

<button id='f'>NEXT FIBONACCI</button>

<div id='r'>_?_<div>
```

Another js library which may be of interest for you is https://github.com/ubolonton/js-csp - did not use it, so not sure how it deals with back pressure.

Answer (score 0):

the idea is to queue the time wait one after the other when the previous one finishes execution [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/br00oq4w/)

```
let a = Rx.Observable.of(1, 2, 3);
let b = Rx.Observable.zip(a, a, (a, b) => a + b);

// getting values into array
var x = [];
b.forEach(t => x.push(t));

var takeEvery = function(msec,items,action,index=0){
  if(typeof(action) == "function")
    if(index<items.length)
        setTimeout(
        function(item,ind){
          action(item);
          takeEvery(msec,items,action,ind);
        },msec, items[index],++index);

};

// queueing over time
takeEvery(1000,x, function(item){
    console.log(item);
});
```